# Python program to decode JSON structure

Tags: python, json

I have the JSON structure shown below and the python code shown below to manipulate the JSON structure.

```
import json

json_input = { 
    "msgType": "0",
    "tid": "1",
    "data": "[{\"Severity\":\"warn\",\"Subject\":\"Reporting \",\"Message\":\"tdetails:{\\\"Product\\\":\\\"Gecko\\\",\\\"CPUs\\\":8,\\\"Language\\\":\\\"en-GB\\\",\\\"isEvent\\\":\\\">
    "Timestamp": "1432703193431",
    "Host": "myserver.com",
    "Agent": "Experience",
    "AppName": "undefined",
    "AppInstance": "my_server",
    "Group": "UndefinedGroup"
}



data = json_input['data']
tdetails = data['Message']
print('json_input {} \n\ndata {} \n\n tdetails {}\n\n'.format(json_input,data,tdetails))
```

I am getting the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_json.py", line 19, in <module>
    tdetails = data['Message']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I want to be able to access the different fields inside `data` such as `severity`, `subject` and also fields inside `tdetails` such as `CPUs` and `Product`. How do I do this?

Comment: Your `json_input['data']` value is *still encoded as JSON*.

Comment: Whatever encoded this should be altered to not encode partial data structures before assembling.

Comment: Clarify your *original question*; we already showed you there you need to decode the nested JSON documents.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The structure that I get is nested as shown in the program.I don't have control over creating the structure. I have to decode the nested JSON

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I can't seem to get `tdetails` out of the structure.

Comment: So use `json.loads(data)['Message']`. You have nested JSON documents, you need to decode each one you find.