# Error while updating a document in ElasticSearch using python es.update()

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am trying to update a document in elasticsearch using the default python interface for Elasticsearch using the below command.

```
res = es.update(index='its', doc_type='vents', id=txid, body={"doc":{"f_vent" :{"b_vent":rx_buffer}}})
```

The updated document is shown below.

```
{
  "_index": "its",
  "_type": "vents",
  "_id": "4752956038",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "ResponseTime": 0,
    "Session": "None",
    "Severity": "warn",
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "Subject": "Reporting Page Load Time",
    "Time": "Fri Jun 05 2015 12:23:46 GMT+1200 (NZST)",
    "Timestamp": "1433463826535",
    "TransactionId": "4752956038",
    "msgType": "0",
    "tid": "1",
    "f_vent": {
      "b_vent": "{\"ActiveTransactions\": 6, \"AppName\": \"undefined\", \"TransactionId\": \"4752956038\",  \"UserInfo\": \"Unknown\"}"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "_timestamp": 1433818222372
  },
  "sort": [
    1433818222372
  ]
}
```

I copied this from Kibana4  discover tab by expanding the document.The 'transaction Id' inside `b_vent` has to be accessed as `f_vent.b_vent.TransactionId`. I suspect this is putting some restricions on me plotting a graph on transaction Id. I tried using

```
res = es.update(index='its', doc_type='vents', id=txid, body={"doc":{"b_vent":rx_buffer}})
```

so that I could use  `b_vent.TransactionId` but I am getting the following error when calling es.update().

```
 raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'MapperParsingException[object mapping for [events] tried to parse field [be_event] as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]')
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem?

This is the almost full strucuture of b_vent.

```
"{
    \"ActiveTr\": 6,
    \"ErrorM\": \"None\",
    \"HError\": \"false\",
    \"HMPct\": 62,
    \"NHMPct\": 57,
    \"Parameter\": \"1433195852706\",
    \"ParameterD\": \"false\",
    \"ProcessCPU\": 1,
    \"Proxies\": \"None\",
    \"RStatusCode\": \"34500\",
    \"Severity\": \"info\",
    \"ThrWtTi\": -1,
    \"ThrWai\": 16,
    \"Timestamp\": \"TueJun0209: 58: 16NZST2015\",
    \"TxId\": \"316029416\",
    \"UserInfo\": \"Unknown\"
}"
```

It does seem to have some strange escape sequences. I am not sure why they are there. But json.loads() does seem to parse the file. I don't know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like the JSON in `f_vent.b_vent` is not correct, it's simply a string as all double quotes are escaped, and thus, `b_vent.TransactionId` is not a valid nested field. That seems heavily related to your other issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701416/removing-leading-and-trailing-backlash-in-key-value-in-json-documents

Comment: @Val - I have updated b_vent strucutre above. It does seem to have some strange escape sequences and doesn't validate on JSON lint. But python json.loads does seem to be able to parse it. I don't know what is happening?

Comment: Those "strange" escape sequence means that your `b_vent` structure seems to be encoded twice and not properly decoded. Have you tried the suggestions offered by people in your other question?

Comment: Moreover, this is also the same issue you're describing at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493220/python-program-to-decode-json-structure